# The closed ball in $\mathbb{C}^n$ is holomorphically convex

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces

A subset $K \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ is holomorphically convex in some open set $X \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ if the set $\{x \in X : |f(x)| \leq \mathrm{sup}_{y\in K}|f(y)| \quad \textrm{for all holomorphic } f: X \to \mathbb{C}\}$ equals $K$.

Let $W \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ be an open ball centred at the origin and let $B \subset W$ be a closed ball centred at the origin. Is it obvious that $B$ is holomorphically convex in $W$?

Comment: I think you are mis-spelling holomorphically  as homomorphically.

Comment: Let $\hat{B}$ denote the holomorphic convex hull of $B$ in $W$, clearly 
$B\subset \hat{B}$. To show the reverse inclusion, just need to take linear functions.

Answer (score 1):

Let $B = \{ s\in \Bbb{C}^n,\sum_j |s_j|^2\le r\}$.  If $s\not \in B$ then $$f(z)=\frac{1}{\sum_j \overline{s_j}z_j - \sum_j |s_j|^2}$$ is holomorphic and bounded on $B$ and it has a pole at $s$ thus $s\not \in HolomorphicClosure(B)$.

If you want the function to be holomorphic on the larger ball $W$ then look instead at $$F(z)=\sum_{k=0}^K (\frac{\sum_j \overline{s_j}z_j}{ \sum_j |s_j|^2})^k$$ (I'm claiming both criteria, in term of holomorphic and meromorphic functions, are equivalent on such simply connected domains in $\Bbb{C}^n$). When $W$ is a compact complex manifold there are no non-constant holomorphic functions so the meromorphic criterion is more natural to me.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! But I thought that, given any $x \in W \setminus B$, we need to be able to find a holomorphic function $f: W \to \mathbb{C}$ (defined on $W$), satisfying $|f(x)| > \mathrm{sup}_{y \in B}|f(y)|$? Your function isn't actually defined at $s$ though?

Comment: Right, then look at $f(z)=\sum_{k=0}^K (\frac{\sum_j \overline{s_j}z_j}{ \sum_j |s_j|^2})^k$ with $K$ large (so I think with this kind of argument both criteria are equivalent)